# HeadlessException and no X11 Display - local machine

Tags: java, swing, exception, awt, headless

I'm trying to instantiate a window, and therefore some graphic classes (swing and awt, essentially) on my PC, locally. The error reported is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException: No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
        at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:165)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:540)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:423)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:388)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:180)
        at RSACoder.<init>(RSACoder.java:255)
        at RSACoder.main(RSACoder.java:557)
```

I don't understand the logical correlation, I'm on laptop with no connection to servers, virtual machines or similar.

I am reporting one part of the code, the part relating to graphics.

```
public RSACoder() {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().setForeground(UIManager.getColor("Button.focus"));
    frame.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.background"));
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 685, 565); 
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    frame.setTitle("RSACoder");
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null); 

    JLabel titolo = new JLabel("Codifica e decodifica secondo algoritmo RSA");
    titolo.setForeground(new Color(204, 0, 51)); 
    titolo.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.PLAIN, 15)); 
    titolo.setBounds(10, 11, 400, 24);
    frame.getContentPane().add(titolo);

    JButton Codifica = new JButton("Salva testo codificato su file");
    Codifica.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    Codifica.setBounds(10, 303, 199, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(Codifica);

    JButton Decodifica = new JButton("Salva testo decodificato su file");
    Decodifica.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    Decodifica.setBounds(10, 367, 210, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(Decodifica);

    JLabel lblKeystorePub = new JLabel("Keystore chiave pubblica");
    lblKeystorePub.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    lblKeystorePub.setBounds(10, 182, 152, 14);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblKeystorePub);

    JLabel lblKeystoreChiavePrivata = new JLabel("Keystore chiave privata");
    lblKeystoreChiavePrivata.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    lblKeystoreChiavePrivata.setBounds(10, 216, 152, 14);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblKeystoreChiavePrivata);

    JButton KeystorePub = new JButton("Nome file in cui salvare chiave pubblica");
    KeystorePub.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    KeystorePub.setBounds(163, 176, 301, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(KeystorePub);

    JLabel filePub = new JLabel("");
    filePub.setBounds(470, 182, 232, 14);
    frame.getContentPane().add(filePub);

    JLabel filePri = new JLabel("");
    filePri.setBounds(470, 216, 232, 14);
    frame.getContentPane().add(filePri);

    JFileChooser fileChooserPub = new JFileChooser(System.getProperty("user.dir"));                                                                                                                                                                                                                 = new JFileChooser(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    JFileChooser fileChooserFileCod = new JFileChooser(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    JFileChooser fileChooserFileDecod = new JFileChooser(System.getProperty("user.dir"));

    KeystorePub.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
                                                        
            fileChooserPub.showOpenDialog(null);
            try {
                filePub.setText(fileChooserPub.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()); 
            } catch (NullPointerException exception) {
                System.out.println("Errore nell'acquisizione del percorso assoluto.");
            }
        }
    });

    JButton KeystorePri = new JButton("Nome file in cui salvare chiave privata");
    KeystorePri.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    KeystorePri.setBounds(163, 210, 301, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(KeystorePri);

    JButton Chiavi = new JButton("Salva chiave su file");
    Chiavi.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    Chiavi.setBounds(10, 244, 171, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(Chiavi);

    JLabel lblKeystore_FileCod = new JLabel("Keystore file codificato");
    lblKeystore_FileCod.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    lblKeystore_FileCod.setBounds(10, 278, 171, 14);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblKeystore_FileCod);

    JButton KeystoreFileCod = new JButton("Nome file su cui salvare il testo codificato");
    KeystoreFileCod.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    KeystoreFileCod.setBounds(181, 272, 283, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(KeystoreFileCod);

    JLabel fileCod = new JLabel("");
    fileCod.setBounds(470, 278, 232, 14);
    frame.getContentPane().add(fileCod);

    JLabel lblKeystore_FileDecod = new JLabel("Keystore file decodificato");
    lblKeystore_FileDecod.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    lblKeystore_FileDecod.setBounds(10, 337, 171, 14);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblKeystore_FileDecod);

    JButton KeystoreFileDecod = new JButton("Nome file su cui salvare testo decodificato");
    KeystoreFileDecod.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    KeystoreFileDecod.setBounds(181, 331, 283, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(KeystoreFileDecod);

    JLabel fileDecod = new JLabel("");
    fileDecod.setBounds(470, 337, 232, 14);
    frame.getContentPane().add(fileDecod);

    JTextArea notes = new JTextArea();
    notes.setEditable(false);// Si imposta il JTextArea come "non modificabile" dall'utente
    notes.setForeground(Color.RED);
    notes.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    notes.setRows(2);// Distribuisci il testo su più righe
    notes.setText(
            "N.B. Verificare di aver specificato tutti i riferimenti ai file per svolgere l'operazione richiesta.");
    notes.setLineWrap(true);// Adatta il testo alla dimensione del JTextArea
    notes.setWrapStyleWord(true);// Distribuisce le parole contenute nel testo in linee
    notes.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.background"));
    notes.setBounds(10, 401, 660, 24);
    frame.getContentPane().add(notes);

    JTextPane autori = new JTextPane();
    autori.setEditable(false);

    StyledDocument style = autori.getStyledDocument(); 
    SimpleAttributeSet align = new SimpleAttributeSet(); 
    StyleConstants.setAlignment(align, StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER); // Imposta l'allineamento centrato
    style.setParagraphAttributes(0, style.getLength(), align, false); // Applica i parametri sopra definiti allo
                                                                        // stile del pannello
    autori.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    autori.setText("Autori:\n▪Luca Boscarato\n▪Christian Rinaldi\n▪Ado Domi\n▪Simone Parisi");
    autori.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.background"));
    autori.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.PLAIN, 13));
    autori.setBounds(0, 436, 700, 92);
    frame.getContentPane().add(autori);

    JLabel lblTextToCrypt = new JLabel("Testo da criptare:");
    lblTextToCrypt.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    lblTextToCrypt.setBounds(10, 46, 152, 14);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblTextToCrypt);

    JTextArea textToCrypt = new JTextArea();
    textToCrypt.setLineWrap(true);
    textToCrypt.setBounds(10, 71, 187, 81);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textToCrypt);

    JLabel lblTextCrypted = new JLabel("Testo criptato:");
    lblTextCrypted.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    lblTextCrypted.setBounds(241, 46, 152, 14);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblTextCrypted);

    JTextArea textCrypted = new JTextArea();
    textCrypted.setLineWrap(true);
    textCrypted.setEditable(false);
    textCrypted.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    textCrypted.setBounds(241, 71, 187, 81);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textCrypted);

    JTextArea textDecrypted = new JTextArea();
    textDecrypted.setLineWrap(true);
    textDecrypted.setEditable(false);
    textDecrypted.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    textDecrypted.setBounds(471, 71, 187, 81);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textDecrypted);

    JLabel lblTextDecrypted = new JLabel("Testo decriptato:");
    lblTextDecrypted.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    lblTextDecrypted.setBounds(473, 46, 152, 14);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblTextDecrypted);

    KeyGenerator(); // si generano la chiave pubblica e privata

    textToCrypt.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        @Override // ridefinizione metodi
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) { // pulsante premuto
        }

        @Override // ridefinizione metodo della superclasse
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) { // pulsante rilasciato
            try {
                textCrypted.setText(encode(textToCrypt.getText(), n)); // scrivi in textCrypted la codifica del
                                                                        // testo in chiaro fino ad ora digitato
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace(); // stampa a video l'eccezione
            }
            if (!textToCrypt.getText().trim().isEmpty()) { // se la casella di testo (JTextArea) contiene qualcosa
                try {
                    textDecrypted.setText(decode(textCrypted.getText(), n)); 
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace(); // stampa a video l'eccezione
                }
            } else
                textDecrypted.setText("");
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) { // pulsante premuto (continuativo)

        }
    });

    KeystorePri.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            fileChooserPri.showOpenDialog(null);
            filePri.setText(fileChooserPri.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()); 
        }
    });

    KeystoreFileCod.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            fileChooserFileCod.showOpenDialog(null);
            fileCod.setText(fileChooserFileCod.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
        }
    });

    KeystoreFileDecod.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            fileChooserFileDecod.showOpenDialog(null);
            fileDecod.setText(fileChooserFileDecod.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
        }
    });

    Chiavi.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { // ActionListener per la creazione delle chiavi.
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (filePri.getText() != "" && filePub.getText() != "") { // Controllo della presenza di ambo i percorsi
                                                                        // per il salvataggio delle chiavi.
                try {
                    KeySaver(filePub.getText(), filePri.getText()); // Salvataggio delle chiavi con i path assoluti
                                                                    // come parametri.
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Chiavi salvate con successo!");
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Errore salvataggio chiavi", "Errore",
                            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); // Messaggio di errore (parametri - ev. componente padre,
                                                        // messaggio, titolo finestra, tipologia di messaggio).
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Inserisci prima keystore chiave pubblica e privata!", "Errore",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    });

    Codifica.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (textCrypted.getText() != "" && fileCod.getText() != "") {
                try {
                    perform(1, textCrypted.getText(), textDecrypted.getText(), textToCrypt.getText(),
                            fileCod.getText());
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "Testo codificato salvato con successo! E' stato creato un file contenente il testo codificato!");
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Errore codifica testo", "Errore",
                            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "Inserisci prima keystore chiave pubblica, testo da codificare e file codificato!",
                        "Errore", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    });

    Decodifica.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (textDecrypted.getText() != "" && fileDecod.getText() != "") {
                try {
                    perform(2, textCrypted.getText(), textDecrypted.getText(), fileCod.getText(),
                            fileDecod.getText());
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File con testo decodificato creato con successo!");
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Errore creazione file con testo decodificato", "Errore",
                            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "Inserisci prima keystore chiave privata, file codificato e file decodificato!", "Errore",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    });
    frame.setVisible(true); // Il frame diviene visibile.
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    RSACoder window = new RSACoder(); 
    return;

}
```

Comment: Are you on Linux? X11 refers to the windowing system on Linux.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Ubuntu (Linux terminal in Windows Subsystem). With Eclipse or VSCode, the code doesn't work too.

Comment: Check you didn't install a headless jvm.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Windows PC and are running Java AWT / Swing / SWT / JavaFX application within Linux (using Linux binaries, not Windows binaries via Windows Subsystem for Linux) then you'll need to install X server on your Windows machine to see the graphical user interface on Windows.

There are various X servers for Windows such as [VxXsrv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/) and [X/Cygwin](https://x.cygwin.com/), plus there are some on Windows Store (X410).

The X server will expect environment variable `DISPLAY` to be set so that GUI appears on the right display. DISPLAY is in the format `host:display[.screen]`. Each X server may have other conventions for setting up permissions to access the Windows host (so preventing others from sending clients to your desktop).

A simple `DISPLAY` value for using the localhost machine which will work for Ubuntu via Windows Subsystem for Linux is `:0` but for remote Linux servers via a terminal in Windows machines you will need the qualified path including your PC `yourhost:0.0`:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
java -cp your.jar your.awt.App
```